# "Branch of/off the main tree"

Tags: verbs

Which should be used: *of* or *off*?

> It is a branch **of/off** the main tree.

The actual context is program code branches and in that context the plural *branches* is not suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can be in a *branch of* the main tree. This would imply that you are in a branch that has already been created.

You can also *branch off* from the main tree. This would imply that you are creating a new branch and separating from the main tree.

The [ODO provides a couple of examples](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/branch) from mainstream usage:

> Sophie was in the *branches of* a tree eating an apple
>
> the road *branched off* at the market town

Comment: +1  In the context of programming:

(1) I'm working in a _branch of_ master (2) Why don't you create a _branch off_ master and work there